# Reverse String MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, masm32

I have this code designed to take a string in "originString" and put it in reverse order in "destinationString". I can't figure out how to make destinationString fill up and not just hold one value and then also print out with writeString and not just writeChar. Here is what i have.

```
INCLUDE     Irvine32.inc
INCLUDELIB  Irvine32.lib

.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
originString        BYTE    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0
destinationString   BYTE    SIZEOF originString DUP(?), 0
counter             BYTE    1




.code
main PROC
    ; YOUR CODE GOES HERE...
    ; Write a procedure that copies the contents of 'originString' to
    ;  'destinationString', but in reverse order.  You should use the
    ;  provided initialization value for 'originString' to test, but your
    ;  solution must work even if the contents or 'originString' are changed.
    MOV EAX, LENGTHOF originString
    MOV ECX, EAX

countLoop_BEGIN:
                    
    MOVZX EAX, counter
    MOV EBX, LENGTHOF originString
    SUB EBX, EAX
    MOV AL, BYTE PTR [originString + (EBX-1)]
    cmp destinationString, ' '
    je   end_shifting
    inc EBX
    MOV destinationString, AL
    MOVZX EDX, destinationString
    CALL WriteString
    ;CALL Crlf
    INC counter

    LOOP countLoop_Begin    ; If ECX IS NOT EQUAL to 0, decrement ECX by 1 and JMP to 'countLoop_Begin'.
                            ; If ECX IS EQUAL to 0, do not jump and move onto the instruction following LOOP.

    MOV destinationString, AL
    MOV EDX, OFFSET destinationString
    CALL WriteString
    CALL Crlf
    end_shifting:    
        ret


    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP



END main
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to make destinationString fill up and not **just hold one value**

In your loop the instruction `MOV destinationString, AL` always writes to the first location of the destinationString. Why don't you index the write much like the way the read from originString works? You can use *counter* for indexing the write too.

This is the quick fix:

```
countLoop_BEGIN:
    MOVZX EDX, counter                  ; 1,2,3,...
    MOV   EBX, LENGTHOF originString
    SUB   EBX, EDX
    MOV   AL, [originString + (EBX-1)]
    MOV   [destinationString + (EDX-1)], AL
    INC   counter
    DEC   ECX
    JNZ   countLoop_Begin
```

---

> and then also print out with writeString and not just writeChar.

For *WriteString* to work, you still need to zero-terminated the destinationString.

```
    MOV   byte [destinationString + EDX], 0
    MOV   EDX, OFFSET destinationString
    CALL  WriteString
```